# Mesibo sdk integration issues

Tags: android

I'm unable to add user from app side and UI is not showing . I have doubt's on these things :
How to add user through this sdk ?
How to use Mesibo chat UI module in our own app ?

Comment: Can anybody help me out for this issues

Answer (score 0):

Yes Mesibo chat sdk integration issues.